# Azure openai account is failing via Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-openai

I am unable to create azure OpenAI account via Terraform. There is no change in the code but all of a sudden I am getting below error:

```
Account Name: "test-chatGPT"): unexpected state 'Failed', wanted target 'Succeeded'. last error: %!s(<nil>)
```

The same code was working before and it was success.

I tried to create the OpenAI account with az cli and it is working. I am not sure what have changed with Terraform.

tf code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source                = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      configuration_aliases = [azurerm.sub_openai_landing_zone]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "openAI" {
  provider                      = azurerm.sub_openai_landing_zone
  name                          = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.name
  location                      = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.location
  local_auth_enabled            = "false"
  resource_group_name           = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.rg_name
  kind                          = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.kind
  sku_name                      = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.sku_name
  public_network_access_enabled = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.public_access
  custom_subdomain_name         = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.custom_subdomain_name
}
```

below is the var file:

```
openai_landing_zone_openAI = {
  skip_role             = "1",
  name                  = "demo-chatgpt",
  location              = "North Central US",
  rg_name               = "demo-rg",
  kind                  = "OpenAI",
  sku_name              = "S0",
  public_access         = false,
  custom_subdomain_name = "demo-chatgpt",
  models = {
    "0"  = {
      name              = "demo-chatgpt-deployment",
      format            = "OpenAI",
      version           = "0613",
      model_name        = "gpt-35-turbo"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share the terraform code you tried to have a better understanding of your blocker you faced.

Comment: @VinayB i have updated the code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to provision the azure openai account via Terraform I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

Based on the error you're seeing, it seems there was an unexpected state 'Failed' during the creation of the Azure OpenAI account using Terraform. There are a few possibilities for this:

1. Azure itself had a transient issue that Terraform detected, but which wasn't present when you tried with the Azure CLI.
2. There might be a difference in the permissions or configurations between your Terraform and Azure CLI setups.
3. There might have been a change or update in the Terraform provider for Azure that introduced this behavior.
4. The issue may also be due name of the resource provided. Try using a unique name for the resource placeholders.

**My terraform configuration:**

##### demo.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source                = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      configuration_aliases = [azurerm.sub_openai_landing_zone]
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias   = "sub_openai_landing_zone"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "openAI" {
  provider                      = azurerm.sub_openai_landing_zone
  name                          = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.name
  location                      = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.location
  resource_group_name           = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.rg_name
  kind                          = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.kind
  sku_name                      = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.sku_name
  public_network_access_enabled = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.public_access
  custom_subdomain_name         = var.openai_landing_zone_openAI.custom_subdomain_name
}
```

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "openai_landing_zone_openAI" {
  description = "Configuration for the OpenAI landing zone"
  type = object({
    skip_role             : string
    name                  : string
    location              : string
    rg_name               : string
    kind                  : string
    sku_name              : string
    public_access         : bool
    custom_subdomain_name : string
    models                : map(object({
      name              : string
      format            : string
      version           : string
      model_name        : string
    }))
  })
}
```

##### terraform.tfvars:

```
openai_landing_zone_openAI = {
  skip_role             = "1",
  name                  = "demo-chatgpt",
  location              = "East US 2",
  rg_name               = "v-sakavya",
  kind                  = "OpenAI",
  sku_name              = "S0",
  public_access         = false,
  custom_subdomain_name = "demovk-chatgpt",
  models = {
    "0"  = {
      name              = "demo-chatgpt-deployment",
      format            = "OpenAI",
      version           = "0613",
      model_name        = "gpt-35-turbo"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes it seems to be issue from Microsoft side and now i can create using same code. Thanks for the information.